# Sending comma separated values to ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have array values like `12345,6789`

When tried passing these values to java script ajax call, i am getting like checkedValues undefined.Kindly help how to pass the checked values array to data in ajax call in this function.

```
function Clicks() {
    var checkedValues = $('input[name="ActualId"]:checked').map(function () {
        return this.id;
    }).get();
    alert(checkedValues); 
    createdatatable();
}


function createdatatable(checkedValues, action) {
    debugger;
    var action = "Approve";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "some url",
        data: JSON.stringify({ eventIds: checkedValues }),
        data: '{ checkedValues:"' + checkedValues + '" ,action:"' + action + }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            alert("yes");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("No");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create you data like this

```
data: { checkedValues: checkedValues , action: action },
```

Or use short form

```
data: { checkedValues, action },//if key:value name is same
```

Also use only one data param

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `+` character after `action`. It's redundant.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some url",
    data: JSON.stringify({ eventIds: checkedValues }),
    data: '{ checkedValues:"' + checkedValues + '" ,action:"' + action '}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("yes");

    },
    error: function () {
        alert("No");
    }
});
```

**You could also build `data` from a variable.**
Create something like:

```
var dataArgs = {
    checkedValues: checkedValues,
    action: action
};
```

and then simply pass `dataArgs` object to `data` key as a value.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some url",
    data: JSON.stringify({ eventIds: checkedValues }),
    data: dataArgs,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (msg) {
        alert("yes");

    },
    error: function () {
        alert("No");
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..:) this helps.. also i forgot to add parameters while calling the function.

Comment: @sri please upvote my answer if you've found that helpful.